# Is there a better way to update html based on input field reactively with Meteor.js?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, meteor, reactive-programming, handlebars.js

I saw this tutorial coding a demo app with Angular.js. Its the Todo demo (http://angularjs.org) where he just types in a text box and it is then reflected on the page easily.

I wanted to re-create this feature in Meteor and it is not working that well. Firstly, for some reason it does not update the last letter. Also the demo video doing this with Angular.js is much easier and works better, is there a better way to do this in Meteor?

Also if there a way to access the DOM instead the helper function? In the events function I can use the 't' variable to access the DOM but in the helpers function I am not sure how, like for example if I wanted to grab text from a div inside the helper function. I am not sure how.

Here is my Meteor code, and here is a live demo: http://todotestapp.meteor.com

Thanks in advance

HTML

```
<head>
  <title>Todo</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <input id="personName" type="text">
  <h1>Hello {{personName}}!</h1>

</template>
```

Meteor Javascript

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
Template.hello.helpers({
    personName: function () {
        return Session.get("personName");
    }
});

Template.hello.events({
    'keypress #personName': function (e, t) {
        Session.set("personName", t.find("#personName").value);
    }
});

}
```

Comment: 1) try using keyup instead of keydown to detect the event. 2) try using the jQuery: $("#personName").val() to grab values since jquery is built in and there's no reason not to use it.

Comment: The keyup works better now, thanks. So inside Template.hello.helpers I tried accessing the DOM using jquery on a different <div id="anotherName"> like you said with: $("#anotherName").val()  and it didn't work. How come?

Comment: what didnt work?...also if keyup worked for you..i'll add it as an answer and you can accept it...

Comment: I accepted your answer thanks! Also is it possible to access the DOM using jquery inside the Template.hello.helpers functions? I tried to and it didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Use the keyup event to detect when a new letter has been entered
2) Use normal jquery to get the value
so do:

```
Template.hello.events({
    'keyup #personName': function () {
        Session.set("personName", $("#personName").val());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use the "input" event.
No need to use jQuery, template instance .find method is fine.

```
Template.hello.events({
    'input #personName': function (e, t) {
        Session.set("personName", t.find("#personName").value);
    }
});
```

This works as expected.

Comment: This works too along with keyup. Do you happen to know if it is possible to use jquery or access the template inside the Template.hello.helpers function?